# Discard All changes not working in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, git, xcode11

I have a project that includes source files from multiple repositories in Xcode 11. When I try to Discard All Changes it lists the repositories but they are grayed out unchecked and I'm not able to check them. When I click Discard nothing happens in my project. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Xcode to solve this.